# Derivative of the Prime Counting Function

Tags: calculus, prime-numbers, dirac-delta

Can it be sufficient to say that $$\pi'(x)=\sum_{p=\mathrm{primes}}\delta(x-p)$$

since there is a spike in $\pi(x)$ at every prime and does not grow at any other value of $x$?

Comment: Only if you were a physicist, in which case I wonder why you're interested.

Comment: Just curious, i was gonna see if I could derive an integral representation of $\pi(x)$.

Comment: But if there were any reasonable integral representation (using the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$), $\pi (x)$ would have to be absolutely continuous, which it is not.
If you don't know measure theory, suffice it to say that indefinite integrals are continuous, but $\pi (x)$ is not.

Comment: I see, but could it suffice to say that the distributional derivative of $\pi(x)$ is equivalent to the sum? Sort of how the Heaviside step function's distributional derivative is the delta function.

Comment: Sure the distributional derivative of $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^x a_n$  is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \delta(x-n)$. Note $\zeta(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \delta(\color{red}{u-\ln n})$ and the Mellin transform of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \color{red}{\frac{1}{n}}\, \delta(x-1/n)$.

Answer (score 0):

if $\{p_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is the sequence of primes, $\pi$ is constant in each interval $(p_n, p_{n+1})$. Therefore, in these intervals, $\pi' \equiv 0$. In the rest of the real line, that is, on each prime $p_n$, $\pi$ is not differentiable since it is not even continuous:

$$
\lim_{x \to p_{n+1}^-} \pi(x) = n \neq n+1 =  \lim_{x \to p_{n+1}^+} \pi(x)
$$

Comment: Ive seen the Dirac Delta function used to assign derivatives to discontinuous functions though, such as the Heaviside step function. I was wondering if it could be applied in this situation to.

Comment: I think I might have misinterpreted your background. I'm not knowledgeable in the Dirac delta nor measure theory, so I can't answer that. In the simplest sense possible, which my answer is referring to, $\pi' \equiv 0$ almost everywhere. If you were to be able to generalize this to $\mathbb{R}$, you should be able to extend $\pi$ to a continuous function. Again, I'm not to experienced on the subject, but $\pi$ is not extendable to a continuous function, so your notion of differentiabilty should be at the very least not the _standard_ one.